# How to setParams on navigation event with UseEffect but outside of a navigate prop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The following code succeeds in setting params and console.log returns an actual Id, but I am unable to pass params to the next screen

```
const addSelection = () => {
  if (!_.isEmpty(props.currentExperience)) {
      navigation.addListener('blur', ()=> {
        navigation.dispatch({
        ...CommonActions.setParams({currentItem: props.currentExperience.experienceId}),
        source:route.key,
      });
    });
  }
  console.log("params is " + route.params?.currentItem)
}

 useEffect(()=> {
  addSelection();
}, [props.currentExperience, addSelection, navigation])
```

on the next screen, the following does not work. And this  `const {currentItem} = route.params` that's closer to the documentation returns "undefined is not an object(evaluating route.params.currentItem"

```
const route = useRoute()
<Text>{route.params?.currentItem}</Text>
```

Comment: How are you getting the `route.key`?

Comment: Do I need to explicitly set a key? I thought the source referred to the current screen and so route.key would read current route's key.... no? I might have misunderstood that then.... what do I need to do?